# Creating multiple pages with inset map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, inset-map

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and I am working with the ModelBuilder.
Now I would like to create multiple maps from a single  layer file, but also use an inset map and background map. The thing is that the layer file has over 2000 records of line features. So I actually would like to cut the layer file into 100x100m (like a puzzle) and then label the line features with information based on values from the attribute table.

Can I use building map books for this and how should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModelBuilder, to my knowledge, does not expose the Data Driven Pages functionality that you access on the toolbar. If you want to automate map output with Data Driven Pages then you must use Python and ArcPy. Search help for DataDrivenPages (arcpy.mapping). From this page there is also a link to building map books.

Answer (score 1):

Hornbydd is correct. There's an out of the box tool to do this called data driven pages. Data driven pages is based on the old school DS Map Book. It gives you the ability to make a map book series and strip maps. There's a handy cartography tool box with a tool for building a polygon index grid over data (like your lines), this in turn can be used in data driven pages.

If the GUI does not give you want you want, you can use arcpy with arcpy.mapping to automate the production of map books.

Help: Data Driven Pages:
[Creating Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003n000000)

Help: Creating an index grid:
[Creating a Grid Index](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Creating_grid_index_features/00s900000025000000/)

Comment: Okay I will have to try that, can I use multiple layers aswell?